# IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString returns HRESULT: -2147024882 (0x8007000E E_OUTOFMEMORY)

Tags: c#, .net-core, rust, clr, clr-profiling-api

I'm playing around with the [unmanaged Profiling interfaces for the CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/profiling-interfaces).

When running with a netcoreapp3.1 or net5.0 console application, in [`ICorProfilerCallback::JITCompilationStarted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-jitcompilationstarted-method) or in [`ICorProfilerCallback::ModuleLoadFinished`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-moduleloadfinished-method), any call to [`IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataemit-defineuserstring-method) to store a string literal in the console app module and return an `mdString` token, returns a HRESULT of -2147024882 (0x8007000E E_OUTOFMEMORY). The call returns this same HRESULT no matter what values are passed to `IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString`.

The .NET application is super simple

```
using System;

namespace dotnetapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING");
            WriteEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_PROFILER");
            WriteEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        static void WriteEnvironmentVariable(string name)
        {
            var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} = {value}");
        }
    }
}
```

and is built and run with

```
dotnet build -c Debug dotnetapp.csproj
dotnet bin/Debug/net5.0/dotnetapp.dll
```

With the relevant Core CLR profiling environment variables set when running the application

```
CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
CORECLR_PROFILER={PROFILER CLSID}
CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH=clr_profiler.dll
```

The profiler is written in Rust using [com-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/com-rs), and the call to `IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString` is defined as

```
impl IMetaDataEmit {
    pub fn define_user_string(&self, str: &str) -> Result<mdString, HRESULT> {
        let mut md_string = mdStringNil;
        let mut wide_string = U16CString::from_str(str).unwrap();
        let len = wide_string.len() as ULONG;
        let ptr = wide_string.as_ptr();
        let hr = unsafe { self.DefineUserString(ptr, len, &mut md_string) };
        if FAILED(hr) {
            log::error!("define user string '{}' failed. HRESULT: {} {:X}", str, hr, hr);
            return Err(hr);
        }
        log::trace!("md_string token {}", md_string);
        Ok(md_string)
    }
}
```

where the unsafe call is to comr-rs generated function

```
com::interfaces! {
    #[uuid("BA3FEE4C-ECB9-4E41-83B7-183FA41CD859")]
    pub unsafe interface IMetaDataEmit: IUnknown {
        // functions ordered by IMetaDataEmit layout
        fn DefineUserString(&self,
            szString: LPCWSTR,
            cchString: ULONG,
            pstk: *mut mdString,
        ) -> HRESULT;
    }
}
```

I'm using `U16CString` to create a `*const u16` pointer in other places in the profiler to pass `LPCWSTR` to interface functions, such as [`IMetaDataImport::EnumMethodsWithName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rometadataapi/nf-rometadataapi-imetadataimport-enummethodswithname), so I don't think this is an issue, but thought I'd mention it.

The log for the failed call is

```
TRACE [imetadata_emit] wide_string UCString { inner: [71, 111, 111, 100, 98, 121, 101, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 0] }, len 14
ERROR [imetadata_emit] define user string 'Goodbye World!' failed. HRESULT: -2147024882 8007000E
```

where `UCString.inner` is the `Vec<u16>` to which a pointer is passed to `IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString`.

`IMetaDataEmit` is retrieved from the stored `ICorProfilerInfo` passed to the profiler on initialize using [`ICorProfilerInfo::GetModuleMetaData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getmodulemetadata-method), using the `CorOpenFlags` `ofRead` and `ofWrite`

```
impl ICorProfilerInfo {
    pub fn get_module_metadata<I: Interface>(
        &self,
        module_id: ModuleID,
        open_flags: CorOpenFlags,
    ) -> Result<I, HRESULT> {
        let mut unknown = None;
        let hr = unsafe {
            self.GetModuleMetaData(module_id, open_flags.bits(), &I::IID as REFIID, &mut unknown as *mut _ as *mut *mut IUnknown)
        };

        if FAILED(hr) {
            log::error!("error fetching metadata for module_id {}, HRESULT: {:X}", module_id, hr);
            return Err(hr);
        }
        Ok(unknown.unwrap())
    }
}
```

where `GetModuleMetaData` is defined on the `ICorProfilerInfo` generated with `com::interfaces!` macro

```
com::interfaces! {
    #[uuid("28B5557D-3F3F-48b4-90B2-5F9EEA2F6C48")]
    pub unsafe interface ICorProfilerInfo: IUnknown {
        // functions ordered by ICorProfilerInfo layout
        fn GetModuleMetaData(&self,
            moduleId: ModuleID,
            dwOpenFlags: DWORD,
            riid: REFIID,
            ppOut: *mut *mut IUnknown,
        ) -> HRESULT;
    }
}
```

It seems like I'm missing something in Rust somewhere. Retrieving data from `ICorProfilerInfo`, `IMetaDataImport`, `IMetaDataImport2` work, as does getting and modifying IL function bodies (changing existing instructions). A thought I had is whether `IMetaDataEmit` might need to be mutable, but I don't think that needs to be the case, as changes to metadata occur on the C++ runtime side of the FFI boundary.

**EDIT**

I put together a simple C++ profiler that calls `IMetaDataEmit::DefineUserString` in `ICorProfilerCallback::ModuleLoadFinished` and that works as expected on the sample .NET application, so this indicates that the issue is in the Rust code somewhere.

Looking through the runtime code, I think [`RegMeta::DefineUserString` is the implementation of `DefineUserString`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/79ae74f5ca5c8a6fe3a48935e85bd7374959c570/src/coreclr/md/compiler/emit.cpp#L1512-L1567) and tracing the code paths, I think the `E_OUTOFMEMORY` is coming from [`StgBlobPool::AddBlob`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0b164711c4df050566e23a1d0e89a22c08a832bd/src/coreclr/src/utilcode/stgpool.cpp#L1524-L1595).

Comment: How is defined your rust IMetaDataEmit?

Comment: @SimonMourier I've added some additional details. I was initially hesitant to add Rust implementation details as there's quite a few of them, but it's looking more likely that the issue is in Rust somewhere

Comment: Can you show the full IMetaDataEmit? There's only one method here.

Comment: OH LORDY... @SimonMourier, you deserve the full bounty for rubber ducking for insisting on seeing the full IMetaDataEmit implementation. It made me go through it in more detail wherein I discovered that I missed a function. If you're happy to post an answer telling me to double check IMetaDataEmit function layout, I'll gladly mark as accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was (apparently) due to an incorrect definition of the `IMetaDataEmit` interface.

Whatever the target language is, a COM interface definition must match the original binary layout exactly: all methods in same order (don't trust MSDN visual order on this), starting with derived interfaces methods (IUnknown, etc.), and exact binary-compatible signature for each method.